# eclipse Invalid location of tag (ol) warning

Tags: html, eclipse, dom, ide

So i have this html setup

```
<ul>
 <li>level one item one</li>
   <ol>
   <li>level two item one</li>
   <li>level two item two</li>
   </ol>
 <li>level one item two</li>
</ul>
```

The structure should be valid even for html 4.01 . however i get the *invalid location tag* warning on eclipse for the nested/inner list.

Any idea why? And how to fix it without making eclipse just ignore that element

Thanks

Comment: `<ol>` is surrounded by `<ul>` but would need to be within an `<li>`

Comment: Thanks! That did it. It wasnt clear from the specs example for nested list at https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [W3.org markup check](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea) `<ol>` does not allow to be within the `<ul>` element directly.

So you have to wrap your `<ol>` element inside a `<li>`, so do this like this:

```html
<ul>
  <li>level one item one</li>
  <li>
    <ol>
      <li>level two item one</li>
      <li>level two item two</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>level one item two</li>
</ul>
```

---

If in any case, you wanted to hide the list style element from `<ol>` part you can do it by CSS styles like this:

```css
ul > li:nth-child(2) {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>level one item one</li>
  <li>
    <ol>
      <li>level two item one</li>
      <li>level two item two</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>level one item two</li>
</ul>
```